# Selecting radial button according to its value jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

what im trying to achieve might be very simple but im stuck. Im tiring to select few radial buttons dynamically with its values by retrieving it from an object when the page loads. Here is what im trying:

```
var t_info = obj.tinfo;
var h_info = obj.hinfo;

$('input[value='+ t_info +']').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('input[value='+ t_info +']').change();
$('input[value='+ h_info +']').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('input[value='+ h_info +']').change();
```

none of the radial buttons get selected on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery 1.6+ you should be using [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

You can also remove 2 lines of code by chaining like so.

```
$('input[value='+ t_info +']').prop('checked', true).change();
$('input[value='+ h_info +']').prop('checked', true).change();
```

Also make sure you are putting your code inside a document ready function so it waits for the dom to actually load before trying to find the elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

or

```
$(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have a map of id-value pairs. (Preferably, JSON)

```
[{ id : '#radio1', value : true },
 { id : '#radio2', value : false }]
```

That way, you could just iterate over them and do

```
$.each(valueMap, function(i, item){
    $(item.id).prop('checked', item.value)
});
```

Comment: im getting the values of the buttons from the previous page through query string,  im able to manipulate all data on the current page except these two sets of radial buttons